# Extension of a $\delta$-subharmonic function that is subharmonic on a reduced domain

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, potential-theory

Suppose $B$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $u$ and $s$ are subharmonic on $B$. Suppose there is a closed subset $F$ of the closure of $B$ with no interior such that $v=u-s$ is subharmonic on $B\setminus F$. Is there a way to prove that $v$ is subharmonic on $B$? Notice that if $u$ and $s$ are $C^{2}$-smooth, the solution is easy: for each $x\in F$ we may take a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $B\setminus F$ that converges to $x$. Then by taking the limit of $\Delta v(x_{n})\geq0$ we can prove the case. But what if $u$ and $s$ are not smooth?

Comment: Something is missing in the statement. What if $F=B$, for example?

Comment: Sorry! I corrected.

Comment: This is not correct: take $u(x)=0,s(x)=|x_1|$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)$  both subharmonic, $v(x)=-|x_1|$ is harmonic away from the line $F=\{ x:|x_1|=0\}$.